# How to get RPM installed package names and versions using RegularExpression in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to parse `rpm -qa` output to get package name and version info. My idea is to search for first occurrence of `r'(-\w+\.)'` (this regex should match the first occurrence of a substring that lies between '-' and '.') and split the data with it. The first part will be the package name and the matched regex with omitted '-' concatenated with second part will be the version.

Example:

- `boost-license-1.36.0-12.3.1`: '-1.' should be first occurrence of the regex matched part
- `boost-license`: The first part after splitting string with `-1.` will be the package name
- `-1.` + `36.0-12.3.1`: from matched part remove '-' and add it to second part to obtain the version.

How to implement this in python and is there any alternate way to identify Package name and version?

boost-license-1.36.0-12.3.1 -> boost-license and 1.36.0-12.3.1

yast2-schema-2.17.5-0.5.42 -> yast2-schema and 2.17.5-0.5.42

release-notes-sles-11.3.34-0.7.1 -> release-notes-sles and 11.3.34-0.7.1

yast2-country-data-2.17.55-0.7.1 -> yast2-country-data and 2.17.55-0.7.1

Code part:

```
command = 'rpm -qa'
pkgList = []
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    client.connect('ipaddress', username='user', password='pwd')
except SSHException as error:
    print (str(error) + "\n"+ "Authentication error")
else:
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    for line in stdout:
        pkgList.append(line.strip('\n'))
    for line in stderr:
        print('' + line.strip('\n'))
```

Comment: could you send a snippet of what you have so far because right now it is unclear what you are asking?Do you already have the data and just want to separate the package name from the version or you are looking for a way to get the data?Please check this link for [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I had data of all the 'rpm-qa' output in a list pkgList. So, pkgList will have data:  aspell-0.60.6-26.22
aspell-32bit-0.60.6-26.22
aspell-en-6.0-160.7
at-3.1.8-1069.22.23.1
at-spi-1.28.1-0.1.161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you could solve part of your problem,i have solved the other half for you:
Here is the simple function for it:

```
def slicer(pkgList):
    #Description: Take packages and slice them into package names and versions
    #Param: pkgList:python list - takes a python list and returns a dict with
    #package name as keys and versions as values

    items = pkgList
    packages = {}
    non_packages = []
    for item in items:
        target = re.search('(-\d+\.)', item)
        try:
            start = item.index(target.group(0))

            package_name = item[:start]
            package_version = item[start+1:]
            packages[package_name] = package_version
        except:
            non_packages.append(item)
    print('Non Packages:\n',non_packages)
    return packages
#returned value is a dict so to get the packages
#packages = slicer(pkgList)
#for names,versions in packages.items():
#    print(names,'\t',versions)
```

Hope this helps
here is my output
[image: Check it out here]

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this in python. I am removing items from the list that don't have regex match.

Eg: gpg-pubkey-307e3d54

There is a reason for using one more list `removedList` to remove elements from `pkgList`. Removing elements directly from `pkgList` misses some elements.

Eg: Removing elements while iterating through the same list will miss some items.

```
for eachPkgVersion in pkgList:
    if(not(p.search(eachPkgVersion))):
        pkgList.remove(eachPkgVersion)
```

The above code removes only 3 items from 'pkgList' even if we have below 6 items

Input:

```
gpg-pubkey-307e3d54
gpg-pubkey-39db7c82
gpg-pubkey-3d25d3d9
gpg-pubkey-50a3dd1c
gpg-pubkey-9c800aca
gpg-pubkey-b37b98a9
```

Output: The list still have below items in it

```
gpg-pubkey-39db7c82
gpg-pubkey-50a3dd1c
gpg-pubkey-b37b98a9
```

Complete Fix:

```
p = re.compile('(-\w+\.)')
removedList = []
for eachPkgVersion in pkgListkgList:
    if(not(p.search(eachPkgVersion))):
        removedList.append(eachPkgVersion)
for eachPkgVersion in removedList:
    pkgList.remove(eachPkgVersion)
for eachPkgVersion in pkgList:
    delimiter = p.search(eachPkgVersion).group(1)
    list = eachPkgVersion.split(delimiter)
    pkgName = list[0]
    pkgVerson = delimiter.strip('-') + list[1]
```